# Structures and conflicting types for function

Tags: c

I am trying to make two functions getFullJulianDay and setJulianDay but when I do I get errors saying that both of them contain conflicting types and I cannot figure out why. I have tried searching and the main reason for conflicting types would be because there are not prototypes but I have the prototypes?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void setJulianDay(struct date *d);
double getFullJulianDay(const struct date *d);
int getIntFromUser(char*, int);
void getDateFromJulian (double jd, int *m, int *d, int *y);
double getDoubleFromUser (char*);
void pause_p(void);

struct date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
    int hour;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
    double julian_day;
};

double getFullJulianDay(const struct date *d)
{
    double julian_day;
    julian_day = getFullJulianDay(d);
}

void setJulianDay(struct date *d)
{

}
```

Comment: Also nice questions! And welcome to upvote rights.

Answer (score 2):

You should define your `struct` before you *ever* use it (say, in a function prototype).